# Why mouse_event doesn't work when Task Manager opened?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, remote-desktop

I am doing a remote desktop application. I have a trouble that I cannot simulate the mouse when Task Manager window at client is opened.

My code:

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dX, int dY, int buttons, int extraInfo);`

It will works fine when I close Task Manager window.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Just a thought, but is the "Always on Top" setting in task manager checked? That might be interfering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I run application at client as administrator then It works well.